# Playing a PC with lycanthrope abilities

Tags: dnd-5e, feats, class, player-characters

I have a player who wants to play a Lycanthrope (werewolf).  But that is technically against the rules.
Using only the 5e official rules form hardcover books, what is the best combination of race/class/feats that would feel like a lycanthrope (werewolf) at early levels (1-5)

Comment: What makes you think that this is "technically against the rules" when there *are* official rules for PC's as Lycanthropes. Also, without more of an idea of what "feel like a lycanthrope" means we can't answer this.

Comment: Are you playing AL?

Comment: Just to expand on Purple's comment: PC Lycanthropes are technically allowed, but they're likely too powerful for low level party, especially with damage immunities that make them virtually indestructible. While your premise was wrong, the question is still a good one; we just need to focus on what aspects of lycanthropy you want to replicate. For example, having a beast form and having a hybrid form are both easily doable, but they would reflect different character options (druid class vs shifter race). A list of "must have" versus "nice to have" elements might help make this answerable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### The *Monster Manual* contains detailed rules for lycanthropy.

The rules for lycanthropy can be found on page 207 of the *Monster Manual* in the sidebar entitled [“Player Characters as Lycanthropes”](https://www.dndbeyond.com/sources/mm/monsters-l#Lycanthropes). So it isn’t “against the rules”, lycanthropy is an optional rule that the DM may choose to include or exclude. So the best race and class combination for a player that has the DM’s permission to be play as a lycanthrope is something like “whatever race and class you want” (note, some DM’s have race and class/subclass restrictions).